# How to constrain loaded swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, security, flash, loader

I load swf files continuously, but if one of the swfs has some defective code such as Mouse.hide() the mouse disappears when the swf is loaded. I want to constrain such malicious code in loaded swfs.

There is also another problem related to containing loaded or loading swfs. When I load a swf which loads another swf to operate, It never completes loading (Event.Complete of contentLoaderInfo) because it needs another swf to load. However, the swf should be loaded before it runs. Since loaded swf is as-2, loader does not give any error. I am also suspicious whether or not it will give error if it is as-3.

Answer (score 0):

Check the LoaderMax classes from greensock.com . This should help solve the problem of swf loading other swf before running, since you can listen to the overall loading progress and react accordingly.

Comment: http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/ It is pretty cool. I am looking at it. If it solves my problem, I will report here.